# Ubuntu 16.04 unknown display

Tags: graphics, 16.04, radeon

I just recently updated to 16.04 and now I'm not able to set resolution for my display. In settings menu my display hangs in unknown state. I've AMD radeon HD5770 video chipset. My dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16273273/ . I just checked here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver that my chipset is supported.

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770] [1002:68b8]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770] [1462:2140]
    Kernel modules: radeon

Any help would be really appreciable!
Thanks!